# Rotating image causes outofmemory Exception

Tags: c#, out-of-memory

When I rotate an image on my the server. It causes an out of memory exception.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Rotates the specified img.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="img">The img.</param>
    /// <param name="rotationAngle">The rotation angle.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Bitmap Rotate(Image img, float rotationAngle)
    {
        //create an empty Bitmap image
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);

        //turn the Bitmap into a Graphics object
        using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            //now we set the rotation point to the center of our image
            gfx.TranslateTransform((float) bmp.Width/2, (float) bmp.Height/2);

            //now rotate the image
            gfx.RotateTransform(rotationAngle);

            gfx.TranslateTransform(-(float) bmp.Width/2, -(float) bmp.Height/2);

            //set the InterpolationMode to HighQualityBicubic so to ensure a high
            //quality image once it is transformed to the specified size
            gfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            gfx.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            gfx.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            gfx.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

            //now draw our new image onto the graphics object
            gfx.DrawImage(img, new Point(0, 0));
        }

        //return the image
        return bmp;
    }
```

The exception is occurring on this line: `gfx.DrawImage(img, new Point(0, 0));`
I've search around the internet and found a number of people with a similar problem, but no solution.

Is there a solution? Or is there another library I can use besides the GDI+ to rotate my images? Maybe there is something in WPF?

**Stacktrace:**

```
[OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory.]
   System.Drawing.Graphics.CheckErrorStatus(Int32 status) +1588745
   System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Int32 x, Int32 y) +227
   System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Point point) +26
   Chucksoft.Core.Drawing.ImageResizer.Rotate(Image img, Single rotationAngle) in C:\Projects\ChucksoftCore\Branches\2.5.0\Source\Chucksoft.Core\Drawing\ImageResizer.cs:245
   Chucksoft.Core.Drawing.ImageResizer.Rotate(Byte[] b, Single angle, ImageFormat format) in C:\Projects\ChucksoftCore\Branches\2.5.0\Source\Chucksoft.Core\Drawing\ImageResizer.cs:22
   TheMemorableMoments.Domain.Services.ImageService.Rotate(IEnumerable`1 media, User user, Single angle) in C:\Projects\TheMemorableMoments\Branches\2.1.0\Source\TheMemorableMoments\Domain\Services\ImageService.cs:34
   TheMemorableMoments.Domain.Services.ImageService.RotateLeft(List`1 media, User user) in C:\Projects\TheMemorableMoments\Branches\2.1.0\Source\TheMemorableMoments\Domain\Services\ImageService.cs:69
   TheMemorableMoments.UI.Controllers.User.PhotosController.Rotate(IMediaFiles media, Action`2 resizeMethod) in C:\Projects\TheMemorableMoments\Branches\2.1.0\Source\TheMemorableMoments.UI\Controllers\User\PhotosController.cs:408
   TheMemorableMoments.UI.Controllers.User.PhotosController.RotateLeft(Media media) in C:\Projects\TheMemorableMoments\Branches\2.1.0\Source\TheMemorableMoments.UI\Controllers\User\PhotosController.cs:396
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +127
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +258
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClassd.&lt;InvokeActionMethodWithFilters&gt;b__a() +125
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +640
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +312
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +709
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +162
   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass8.&lt;BeginProcessRequest&gt;b__4() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1.&lt;MakeVoidDelegate&gt;b__0() +20
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +453
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: How large is your image?

Comment: It's 2 to 3 megs. The server it's on has 4 gigs.

Comment: That's odd.  Nothing sticks out at me to think there was a memory leak.  As far as debugging goes, have you tried just drawing on the bitmap without any transformation?  Try to find which property would cause the exception to narrow it down a bit.  Is the leak isolated to this function or did it just happen to run out of memory on this particular call?

Comment: Have your code disposed the returned `Bitmap` after finished using it?

Comment: All Bitmaps are disposed. Still getting errorage...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. I never figured out the "Out Of Memory" Exception. Instead I used the RotateFlip method hanging of the Image Class. Looking at the RotateFlip code, in Reflector, it's a direct call into the Native Library. The drawback to this method, is you can only rotate in 90 degree increments. For me it's works great.